# Loading pictures in Chrome

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, image

On some occassion, Google Chrome download a line (of maybe 20px) at a time and display it right away. So the picture is rendered from top to bottom. Using html  tag results in this.

On other occasion, Google Chrome displays a picture from facebook photos in an interleaving way, first a bit grainy, and then it becomes clearer as more data has been downloaded.

This way the picture is displayed wholly at first with low resolution and the resolution is getting higher as if it's being streamed.

Is there a special tag to do this "streaming" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct word is "interlace" - when you save the image in some web formats (.jpeg for example), you often have the option to save it *interlaced* - I know this option exists in Photoshop's "Save for Web".

So it's not an html tag - it's the way the image is encoded. And then the browser has to be capable of "streaming" interlaced images (most modern ones are).

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the "interlace". why don't I see this every time i try to view a jpg image in Google chrome ?

Comment: Because few people bother to interlace their images - it's an archaic technique that belongs to the age of dial-up modems, and interlacing actually increases the image file size sometimes

Comment: Looks like that Chrome does not even support interlaced pngs. It loads the whole image before displaying the content (Firefox goes from low to high resolution)